# Dynamically assigning data-role attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I thought I could add this before calling jQuery Mobile's JavaScript:

```
$('section').data('role','page');
$('article').data('role','content');
```

And that way I could simply use `<section>` and `<article>` tags in my HTML instead of specifying `<div data-role="page">` and `<div data-role="content">`.

But I don't think it's working.

Comment: Your jQuery calls might be running after the jQuery mobile is loaded

Comment: Maybe I could add a defer attribute to the jQuery mobile JavaScript to make sure that it runs last?

Comment: Tell me when you want to add it and I will make you an example? It can be done in numerous ways.

Comment: I believe that it needs to run just before script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js">

Comment: @MikeLegacy That wasn't me!  I up-vote people but can't remember ever downvoting anyone.

Comment: Sorry then brother, my mistake! My answer is a little vague, but I didn't know if changing the attribute with jquery would be different that changing it with .data(). But yes, I would just make sure your scripts are BEFORE the mobile file is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
$('section').attr('data-role','page');
$('article').attr('data-role','content');
```

Comment: Haha, thank you buddy. No hard feelings lol, it was literally was downvoted like 3 seconds after I submitted it. I was like WTF lol

Comment: Well, yours is actually the accepted answer because it's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**head:**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="YOUR-SCRIPT.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

**YOUR SCRIPT JS:**

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $('section').data('role','page');
    $('article').data('role','content');
    /* OR */
    $('section').attr('data-role','page');
    $('article').attr('data-role','content');
});
```

Reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 1):

Why do you require "data-" attributes? http://api.jquery.com/data/
They can cause memory leaks amongst other issues. jQuery already has a built-in 'data', and it is working. It does not set data- attributes, it uses a better, more efficient means of storing data associated with a DOM selector with JavaScript.

If you for some reason don't have 'data' built in, you should update jQuery. Here is a shim, mostly so you can see how it could work. It is not a complete shim, it's just a very simple way to store data with the selector of an element of the data's key. I don't delete the data when the element is deleted, so my implementation may cause memory leaks. It's just an example, though.

```
if ($(window).data === undefined) {
    $.fn.data = (function () {
        var storage = {};
        return function data (name, val) {
            var id = $(this).selector;
            storage[id] = storage[id] || {};   
            if (val === void 0) {
                return storage[id][name];
            }
            storage[id][name] = val;
            return $(this);
        }
    }());
}

var foo = $('section').data('role','page');
var bar = $('article').data('role','content');
foo.text(foo.data('role'));
bar.text(bar.data('role'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dETuh/1/

Notice the alert doesn't run, so my shim isn't even being used..

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(window).data === undefined) {
    $.fn.data = (function () {
        var storage = {};
        return function data (name, val) {
            var id = $(this).selector;
            storage[id] = storage[id] || {};   
            if (val === void 0) {
                return storage[id][name];
            }
            storage[id][name] = val;
            return $(this);
        }
    }());
}

var foo = $('section').data('role','page');
var bar = $('article').data('role','content');
foo.text(foo.data('role'));
bar.text(bar.data('role'));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, don't just post a block of code.